# How much water is too much?

Tags: toddler, water

My 12 1/2 month old loves water. He will drink it whenever it's offered. He is currently being nursed 2-3 times a day, having 3 solid meals and 1 or 2 small snacks, and occasionally gets an ounce or 2 of milk with his meals. He has recently mastered his sippy cup, and I offer him water at meals and occasionally throughout the day. If I leave a sippy cup near him as he plays, he drinks from it often.

It's hot, so increased thirst is understandable. I was just wondering what's a normal amount of water for this age? Especially since he has started leaking through his diaper every single night :) Would there be any reason to limit his water intake, or can I let him drink as much  as he wants?

Comment: Children are good at self-regulating water intake. They won't usually have more than they need. I think it will be fine to just let him have as much as he wants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say let him drink as much as he wants: that's what his kidneys are for. True, it will mean more diaper changes (and so possibly more waking up overnight), but it won't hurt him.

As for a "normal" amount of water, that depends on the child's body mass, food intake, climate, and a lot of other factors.

Comment: +1 for _as much as he wants_ especially when it's just water, but avoid fluid intake 1-2 hours before bedtime to reduce the night diaper problem.

Comment: Does giving too much water can lower the level of an important minerals?